# Pass arguments in django test

Tags: python, django, django-tests

I am trying to pass both the `user.id` and `sample.id` to a function in the views.

Here is my urls.py (url only accepts `sample.id` )

```
path('<int:tag>', views.task, name='task'),
```

Here is my views.py (views.py is looking for `user.id` but cannot find it)

```
def task(request, tag):
    task_user = get_object_or_404(Team, id=tag)

    task_user.assigned_to = ProjectUser.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('user_id'))
    task_user.save()
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('someOtherPage'))
```

Here is my html template

```
<form method='POST' action="{% url 'task' object.id %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="select1"></label>
    <select name="user_id" class="mdb-select md-form" id="select1" onChange="form.submit();">
        {% for user in usernames %}
            <option value="{{ user.id }}"> {{ user }} </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</form>
```

Here is my tests.py

```
def someTest(self):

    self.client.login(username='jack', password='123')
    user1 = auth.get_user(self.client)
    assert user1.is_authenticated

    sample = Team.objects.create(sampleField='SampleName')

    request = self.client.post(reverse('analyst_view_app:task_analyst', kwargs={'tag': sample.id}))
```

The error message is:

> SomeApp.SomeModel.ProjectUser.DoesNotExist: ProjectUser matching query
>   does not exist.

How can I pass the `user1.id` from my test to the function `task` -> `user_id` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not passing any POST data in your test. You need to send a dictionary representing the data from the form, as the second argument to the `client.post()` call.

```
request = self.client.post(
    reverse('analyst_view_app:task_analyst', kwargs={'tag': sample.id}),
    {'user_id': user1.id}
)
```

(Note though, if your view is supposed to be always getting the logged-in user, there doesn't seem to be any point in the select box at all. If not, then you should change your test; perhaps you don't need to log in at all there?)

Comment: sorry I did not understand you note. The view is only suppose to get logged in user yes, what `select box ` are you referring to in this case ?

Comment: The form has a select box to allow you to choose a user to submit. What's the point, if you always want the logged-in one anyway?

Comment: I see what you mean, in the html above the `usernames` contains all the users as a select as you mentioned, but for the test purposes as I cannot simulate choosing a user, I am pretending that the logged in user is the selected user.